# .htaccess alternative to B flag? (escape backreferences)

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess set up with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ profile.php?aid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This gets a users profile perfectly fine, however if their username is for example "apple & pears" I get a 404 page not found. I believe this is down to some encoding issue with the ampersand. I've researched and found that the B flag would solve this problem, however my host's Apache version is below 2.2.7 when this was introduced.

Is there any method to replicate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have 2 separate rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^&]+)&([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?aid=$1\%26$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?aid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That would solve the solution if there was only one ampersand what if there was multiple?

Comment: You wrote its a user profile and these are real usernames. Thinking about `username` how many `&` can they really have in there? Real solution is to use `B` flag but consider this a workaround solution.

Comment: I understand that, but it's not a generic user. Without giving away my project I can't really say. But what if the user had spaces included also. So say this was a username, "Robert-Smith-&-Kline"

Comment: `Robert-Smith-&-Kline` works fine or even `Robert Smith & Kline` also works fine. Spaces or hyphens are all okay, wish you would have tried it yourself.

Comment: I've tried this but I get 404 page not found when it has an ampersand. However usernames like "Robert-Smith" would load fine.

Comment: It worked for me with all the test strings you provided like: `Robert-Smith-&-Kline` or even `Robert Smith & Kline`. Most likely your old Apache version is the main problem and not recognizing `\%26`

Comment: I think I will just need to speak to my host about upgrading or switching to a new host. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: You're welcome, its been a work around anyway since best solution is definitely upgrading to the latest Apache.

Comment: One more work around I would recommend till you get upgrade. Rather than reading `$_GET['aid']` inside `index.php` access `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` which will be: `aid=Robert & Smith & Kline` for the case of this URL: `http://domain.com/Robert & Smith & Kline`. You can then easily split/explode by `=` to get your required value.